# SSH Interactive mode not working

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, tty

I have a Debian based linux server running for a year or so, without any problems. A couple of days ago, ssh interactive mode stopped working for no reason. I mean, I can open an ssh connection just fine, the server greets me with shell but I just can't type anything. However, if I send commands like this: `ssh user@server.com cat /var/log/messages`, I get the response.

I dug through several logs and found one message, which feels remotely relevant to the problem;

```
sh kernel: [10222733.062511] ------------[ cut here ]------------
sh kernel: [10222733.062522] WARNING: at /build/buildd-linux-2.6_2.6.32-39-amd64-7yVIH2/linux-2.6-2.6.32/debian/build/source_amd64_none/drivers/char/tty_ldisc.c:738 tty_ldisc_reinit+0x46/0x7b()
sh kernel: [10222733.062526] Hardware name: PowerEdge R210 II
sh kernel: [10222733.062528] Modules linked in: ipt_MASQUERADE iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv4 ip_tables x_tables sha1_generic arc4 ecb ppp_mppe ppp_async crc_ccitt ppp_generic slhc loop snd_pcm snd_timer snd soundcore snd_page_alloc i2c_i801 i2c_core pcspkr evdev joydev dcdbas container button processor ext3 jbd mbcache sg sd_mod sr_mod crc_t10dif cdrom usb_storage usbhid hid mpt2sas ahci ehci_hcd libata scsi_transport_sas usbcore bnx2 nls_base scsi_mod fan thermal thermal_sys [last unloaded: scsi_wait_scan]
sh kernel: [10222733.062568] Pid: 8662, comm: sshd Not tainted 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1
sh kernel: [10222733.062569] Call Trace:
sh kernel: [10222733.062572]  [<ffffffff811ff056>] ? tty_ldisc_reinit+0x46/0x7b
sh kernel: [10222733.062574]  [<ffffffff811ff056>] ? tty_ldisc_reinit+0x46/0x7b
```

Is there any way to get back the sshd working in interactive mode? I tried restarting sshd but that is no help. And somehow, I can not reboot the server. Tried sending `shutdown -r now` and `reboot` but it refuses to go down.

Should I go ahead and request a physical reboot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's going to require a forced reboot, yes; the tty/pty driver has become deranged (`ldisc` is a shared layer containing the `termios` stuff and line buffering; on some OSes a different ldisc is used for PPP/dialup networking).